# C: Merging sorted linked list - move pointers only

Tags: c, merge, linked-list

I have two sorted linked lists, list1 and list2.
My goal is to merge list2 into list1.

The requirements are as follows:

1. The resulting list should be list1 (no creating a new linked list and having the merged list to be in the new linked list)
2. The return type must be void
3. list2 must be empty after the merge
4. Merged list must be sorted
5. Cannot delete or remove any nodes. Move pointers only
6. No recursions
7. No sorting allowed in the algorithm
8. No other helper functions

Sample output:

- list1: d -> e -> f -> t -> w -> x -> y -> NULL
- list2: a -> b -> e -> j -> l -> z -> NULL

Result:

- list1: a -> b -> d -> e -> e -> f -> j -> l -> t -> w -> x -> y -> z
  -> NULL
- list2: empty

My code's result is currently

- list1: d -> e -> f -> j -> l -> t -> w -> x -> y -> z -> NULL
- list2: a -> b -> d -> e -> e -> f -> j -> l -> t -> w -> x -> y -> z
  -> NULL

```
typedef struct listNode {
        char data;
        struct listNode* nextPtr;
} ListNode;
        
typedef ListNode* ListNodePtr;


void mergeSortedList(ListNodePtr list1, ListNodePtr list2) {

    ListNodePtr curr = NULL;
    ListNodePtr last = NULL;

    if (list1->data < list2->data)
    {
        curr = list1;
        last = list1;
        list1 = list1->nextPtr;
    }
    else {
        curr = list2;
        last = list2;
        list2 = list2->nextPtr;
    }
    last->nextPtr = NULL;

    while (list1 != NULL && list2 != NULL) {
        if (list1->data < list2->data) {
            last->nextPtr = list1;
            last = list1;
            list1 = list1->nextPtr;
        }
        else {
            last->nextPtr = list2;
            last = list2;
            list2 = list2->nextPtr;
        }
        last->nextPtr = NULL;
    }

    if (list1 != NULL) {
        last->nextPtr = list1;
    }
    else {
        last->nextPtr = list2;
    }
}
```

Comment: `mergeSortedList` with this signature cannot possibly work under these restrictions. Consider this function call `mergeSortedList(list1, list2)`. If before the call `list1` points to node X and `list2` points to node Y, then after the call `list1` points to node X and `list2` points to node Y, regardless of what the function is doing.

Comment: Please update example to be a self-contained program (includes, main etc).

Comment: I think, you need to create a new list, and not using the old pointers, as you will broke the old lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Eliminate `ListNodePtr` in favor of `ListNode *` (see [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)).
2. As @n.m. implied you need to pass in `ListNode **` in order to have an effect on caller.
3. If either `list1` or `list2` are NULL original code segfaults.
4. Swap the two lists if `*list1` doesn't point to the smallest first node.  Then iterate through the two lists using the pointers `l1` and `l2`.  The interesting case is moving nodes from `l2` to `l1`.  This requires you to look ahead a node on `l1`m so you can set the inbound pointer to the node being move.  Alternatively keep a pointer around to the previous node on `l1` than the one we currently looking. Finally, deal with any remaining nodes of `l2`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct listNode {
    char data;
    struct listNode* nextPtr;
} ListNode;

ListNode *createList(const char *data) {
    if(!data || !*data) return NULL;
    size_t n = strlen(data);
    ListNode *head = malloc(n * sizeof(*head));
    if(!head) return NULL;
    ListNode *p = head;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++, p = p->nextPtr) {
        p->data = data[i];
        p->nextPtr = p + 1;
    }
    (p-1)->nextPtr = NULL;
    return head;
}

void mergeSortedList(ListNode **list1, ListNode **list2) {
    if(!*list1 || (*list2 && (*list1)->data > (*list2)->data)) {
        ListNode *tmp = *list1;
        *list1 = *list2;
        *list2 = tmp;
    }
    if(!*list1) return;
    ListNode *l1 = *list1;
    ListNode *l2 = *list2;
    while(l1->nextPtr && l2) {
        if(l1->nextPtr->data <= l2->data)
            l1 = l1->nextPtr;
        else {
            ListNode *tmp = l2->nextPtr;
            l2->nextPtr = l1->nextPtr;
            l1->nextPtr = l2;
            l2 = tmp;
        }
    }
    if(l2) l1->nextPtr = l2;
    *list2 = NULL;
}

void printList(const char *name, ListNode *head) {
    printf("%s: ", name);
    for(; head; head = head->nextPtr) {
        printf("%c -> ", head->data);
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}

int main(void) {
    ListNode *l1 = createList("deftwxy");   
    ListNode *l2 = createList("abejlz");
    mergeSortedList(&l1, &l2);
    printList("list1", l1);
    printList("list2", l2);
}
```

and resulting output:

```
list1: a -> b -> d -> e -> e -> f -> j -> l -> t -> w -> x -> y -> z -> NULL
list2: NULL
```